# How are sightstones recharged?

Tags: league-of-legends

Of the few times I've played support and have managed to acquire this item at late game, I've tended to resourcefully use this as much as possible until my team encounters a baron fight/steal situation which demands me to ward the whole area taking up all four of my charges.
I never have a chance to actually test this 'ward recharge' myself as the final fight at baron regardless of which team wins ends the game almost every time at that point as a result of a team ace.

I'm curious what actually qualifies as 'visiting the shop' in order for me to recharge my sightstone.

Do I need to recall to the spawnpool to qualify as a recharge? Or do I have to physically open the shop and purchase an item every time?

P.S. I am dreadful at support so I tend to avoid it.

Comment: Getting it late game isn't the best time. You should go for it as quickly as possible. preferably after your philo stone and then choose between boots or sightstone...

Comment: Not to mention can't you only use 2 wards on a normal and 3 on the ruby?

Comment: @SirKsilem You're better off getting sightstone over philo if you can afford it.

Comment: @snuffleupagus philo over sightstone everytime.

Comment: @Paralytic nah, sightstone grants you more gold in savings than philo does in gp/10 and the regen loss can be countered with pots. Sightstone gives you 2 ward vision for 6 minutes, ie 4 wards, which would cost you 400g in green wards. In a 6 minute period philo stone would grant you 180g. Even buying 4  pots you come out 80g ahead. This is also ignoring the benefit of having a free replacement against pinks and the ability to shift them if need be and more importantly the large chunk of health you get. Really sightstone is heart of gold 2.0 if you plan on having constant wards.

Comment: @Snuffleupagus I never saw it that way. I'll try it next game ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[@Raven Dreamer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/336)'s answer is actually misleading.

[image: Image showing the zones]
Red: Item Recharge Zone
Blue: Shopping Zone
Green: Healing Zone

Specific to OP's question, the Sight Stone will not recharge unless you move inside the red zone (stepping on the line also counts).

The reason Reaper is incorrect is because, as you can see, the blue shopping zone is centered around the shop keeper and not the center of the spawn circle. This lets you buy while you stand outside of the spawn fountain (to the top left) and also unable to buy even when standing on the fountain (to the bottom right).

Here is a quick and dirty list of what applies to each zone:
(Keep in mind, to get each zones effect, you only need to at least step on the boarder)

Red: Recharge Zone
      - BOTH red and blue sight stones
      - Crystalline flask
      - Homeguard Boots (There is an invisible cool down on Homeguards)

Green: Healing Zone
      - Rapid health restore (ignite effects still cut this healing in half)
      - Rapid mana/energy restore
      - Fountain laser will hit enemies inside this zone

Blue: Shopping Zone
      - Interact with the store

Comment: neat stuff, + 1

Answer (score 12):

You need to get back on the initial summoning platform (where you revive and recall to).

Beyond that, everything else is automatic. If you die or use recall, you'll refresh your sighstones for sure.